# Editing previous source files to run different code on visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I have been reading C for Dummies book, and there was this example where I can edit my previous source code and then save it to a different name. But when I run the code, it ran the previous code. I only made some small changes. How do I run the new code on visual studio 2013? I always keep ending up creating a new project, is there a solution to this?

Comment: if you save to a different name, you must also remove the old file from your project, and add the new file. But a new project is probably easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have many options , one option I prefer is :

1-Make a duplicate of the file you want to edit ; you can make this by copying the code and pasting it into a new file with a different name.

2-Make the changes you want to do on  the new file.

3-Exclude the first file from build by right click , properties and then exclude from build.

you are now having the original copy of the file excluded from build , and you have an edited version for it .

Also: Don't forget to make backup copies of your edited files occasionally ,